# ionic3 android status bar no icon shown

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3, statusbar

When I update my project ionic version, the android app have status bar can't show any icon when enter to the app:

[image]

When enter to app:

[image]

Anyone know how to solve?
My info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.17.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.17.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.6.0-nightly.2017.11.22.24bfb734
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Comment: any update on this ? i am having same issue :(

Answer (score 13):

I have resolved with

```
statusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
```

instead of

```
statusBar.styleDefault();
```

Comment: Worked for me as well, Ionic v4

Answer (score 12):

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            if (platform.is('android')) {
                statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
                statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: worked with me, but just import `import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';`

Comment: Worked for me ionic5. All I need was `statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);`

Answer (score 3):

I found this helpful. You can use one of these three options in ionic 3

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // for Black
      if(this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.statusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use one for a hex code color

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#fff');
```

This one for a light colored theme that is built in.

```
this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app.component.ts
Check that you have

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
...   

@Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {

      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          statusBar.styleDefault();
          splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
```

And just to be safe, run the following commands.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

When all that is done. Generate your Apk with your favorite command or you can try this too

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `statusBar.styleDefault()` to `statusBar.styleLightContent()` at `app.component.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Install below Plugins:

- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
- npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
  [image]

Include below code in your app.component.ts

```
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(<<STATUS_BAR_COLOR>>);
}
```

```html
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { EventProvider } from "./event-provider.service";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private eventProvider: EventProvider
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.eventProvider.currentLang.subscribe(lang => {
      this.translate.use(lang);
    });
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#04b9fe');
    }
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Show Status Bar In Ionic 4 Application

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
      ) {
        this.initializeApp();
    
      }
      initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.statusBar.show();
      }
     }
    }
```